# C++ - What happens if I `return a*= b;`?

Tags: c++, c++11, semantics

So..  I was writing some code and wanted to know the prototype for a compound operator (i.e. something like `operator*=` or `operator/=`).  When I looked it up I realized that they're supposed to return references.  (Or at least my source indicated as such: [`R& operator +=(K& a, S b);`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators) .)  Well..  I then realized that a line in my code might be a little more dangerous than it appeared to be:

```
// I have a really fancy Vector class I've been making. :P
template<typename T, int N>
inline Vector<T, N> operator*(const Vector<T, N>& vec, T scale) {
    Vector<T, N> ret = vec;
    return ret *= scale;
}
```

So.. I was wondering if this is harmless... or will cause a reference to a local variable to leak out and cause all kinds of undefined behavior and general havoc.  (I'm leaning towards havoc, and, as such, rewrote it as below. :P )

```
// I have a really fancy Vector class I've been making. :P
template<typename T, int N>
inline Vector<T, N> operator*(const Vector<T, N>& vec, T scale) {
    Vector<T, N> ret = vec;
    ret *= scale;
    return ret;
}
```

So.. yea.. general C++ "what if?" question here.  Would be nice to know for sure.  (And I was too lazy to try and make a test case and see if my program halted and caught fire. :P )

**EDIT:**  After fixing the above code.. I realized it might help to put said compound operator here as well. :P

```
template<typename T, int N>
inline Vector<T, N>& operator*=(Vector<T, N>& vec, T scale) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        vec[i] *= scale;
    }
    return vec;
}
```

So..  with the code corrected (and double-checked) I'm wondering if using that first variant will still cause the dangling reference or not (because the return type of `operator*=` is a reference).

Comment: As far as I see, both your examples do the same thing: they return a reference to a local variable which immediately goes out of scope and no longer exists.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Surely they don't...  the latter, for sure, does NOT return a reference to a local variable.  The former.. well that was my question!  EDIT:  Well.. I looked at it again and I see it now..  Ignore this. :P

Comment: @CorneliaXaos The return type of both versions of the function is `Vector<T, N>&`, which is a reference, and you are returning `ret`, which is a local variable. Therefore, you are returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @JosephThomson Yea..  I botched the return type when I was typing it up and I didn't check it first..  They're not actually returning by reference in my code.  Only the compound operators are doing so.

Answer (score 5):

By convention, compound assignment operators like `*=` should return a reference to the object they modify, as there is no reason to make an unnecessary copy. That said, even in your modified example you will get a "dangling" reference, as you are still returning a reference to a local variable which will have been destroyed after the function returns. You should return by value instead of by reference.

```
template <typename T, int N>
Vector<T, N> operator*(Vector<T, N> const& vec, T scale) {
    Vector<T, N> ret = vec;
    return ret *= scale;
}
```

Note also that you can get rid of `ret` if you pass `vec` by value. This may allow for more efficient client code if `Vector<T, N>` can be moved more efficiently than it can be copied.

```
template <typename T, int N>
Vector<T, N> operator*(Vector<T, N> vec, T scale) {
    return vec *= scale;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I need to do something similar to the latter example you provide (but the input vec should still be const).

Comment: @CorneliaXaos: The input should not be `const`, it's pass-by-value which either copies or moves the operand as appropriate.  And then the return moves the result.

Comment: @CorneliaXaos I have updated my answer in response to your edits.

Comment: @JosephThomson I clarified further while you were updating (maybe?) and your modifications are interesting.. I've never seen `const&` before..  Also, passing by value could be expensive (in theory) since that `N` is the size of the Vector so it could potentially be hundreds large.

@BenVoigt The input value needs to be const as I, indeed, need to be able to scale Vectors that might be const themselves.  The return should not be by reference in the case of `operator*`.

Comment: @CorneliaXaos: A by-value parameter can be constructed from a `const` operand, because the copy constructor accepts a const reference.

Comment: @CorneliaXaos Sorry. I shouldn't have changed `const T&` to `T const&`; the meaning is identical, so ignore my compulsive stylistic changes. Regarding the copy, with `operator*`, you need to make a copy somewhere since you are not modifying an existing object. If you use the pass by value technique and make your type efficiently movable, then you can avoid an expensive copy when passing rvalue `Vector`s as operands.

Comment: @Joseph: However the first version permits NVRO, while the second one does not.  (if inlining happens, both can be optimized fully)  The always-efficient version is to use perfect forwarding to initialize a named local, which will be constructed in-place in the return value area.

Comment: @BenVoigt Except I want to pass by value since the Vector may be initialized with INT_MAX if you so desired...  Therefore, passing by reference makes more sense to me.  (Also, I am inlining them on my machine.. I just didn't add that keywork up there.)

Comment: @JosephThomson So..  the first example in your answer is valid?  It doesn't cause a dangling reference problem? (If that's correct, it's because even though `operator*=` returns a reference the function itself returns by value which essentially makes a copy, correct? ... it seems so obvious now that I type it out.)

Comment: @CorneliaXaos: When you pass by reference, you then have to initialize a local variable to use to hold the results, and that initialization is always a copy (unless you use perfect forwarding).  With pass by value, the caller can decide how to setup the value, and will use a move when possible.

Comment: Also yes, the parenthesized part of your comment is exactly correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt "you have to initialze a local variable to use to hold the results"... of the function?  Well.. yea..  you're going to have to put your result somewhere...  Perfect Forwarding is not a technique I'm familiar with...

And.. while this might sound a little blunt, it would be best to just answer a question and not force potential optimizations on someone.  You cloud the answer to the question by attempting to optimize the example code which is often simplified for the sake of the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah. I forgot about RVO. I'm not entirely clean about when it does and doesn't happen, so maybe I'll read up about it. I dislike perfect forwarding in a situation like this because it kind of skirts around the type system. Presumably you could get the same effect by providing both lvalue and rvalue reference overloads?

Comment: @JosephThomson: NRVO (which may become mandatory in C++17) is generally going to happen when the compiler can choose to put the `ret` variable directly in the space the calling convention reserves for the return value.  In the second case, the returned value `vec` is already placed in parameter-passing space by the caller, so RVO isn't possible.  And yes, writing lvalue- and rvalue-reference overloads is just as good as a template for perfect forwarding, just remember that an rvalue reference parameter is an lvalue, so you have to call `std::move` in the rvalue reference version.

Answer (score 1):

(While @JosephThomson's answer below "answers" the question, it's not spelled out as simply as I feel it should be so I'm providing the answer here.)

```
template<typename T, int N>
inline Vector<T, N> operator*(const Vector<T, N>& vec, T scale) {
    Vector<T, N> ret = vec;
    return ret *= scale;
}
```

The `return ret *= scale;` in the above **does not** cause a dangling reference error.  The reason being that the return type is `Vector<T, N>` and is **not** a reference type.  Because of this, even though `operator*=` is defined to return a reference type, a copy is produced when `operator*` returns (effectively stripping the reference).

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

If you define the operator in the class it takes one parameter and you modify the classes data and return *this without returning a local variable:

```
R& K::operator *=(S b);
```

If you define the operator outside the class it takes two parameters and you modify that parameter and return that parameter without returning a local variable:

```
R& operator *=(K& a, S b);
```

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators under Canonical Implementations they have this example:

```
class X
{
 public:
  X& operator+=(const X& rhs)     // compound assignment (does not need to be a member,
  {                               // but often is, to modify the private members)
    /* addition of rhs to *this takes place here */
    return *this; // return the result by reference
  }

  // friends defined inside class body are inline and are hidden from non-ADL lookup
  friend X operator+(X lhs,        // passing lhs by value helps optimize chained a+b+c
                     const X& rhs) // otherwise, both parameters may be const references
  {
    lhs += rhs; // reuse compound assignment
    return lhs; // return the result by value (uses move constructor)
  }
};
```